# Mongodb: Shard a collection within my python code

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, sharding

I have a distributed MongoDB 3.2 database. The system is mounted on two nodes with RedHat operating system.

Using python and the PyMongo driver (or some other), I want enable the sharding of a collection, specifying the compound shard key.

In the mongo shell this works:

```
> use mongotest
> sh.enableSharding("mongotest")
> db.signals.createIndex({ valueX: 1, valueY: 1 }, { unique: true })
> sh.shardCollection("mongotest.signals", { valueX: 1, valueY: 1 })
```

('mongotest' is the DB, and 'signals' is the collection)

The last two lines I want to make them within my code. Does anyone know if this is possible in python? If so, how is it done?

thank you very much,
sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct translation of your shell commands to python is as shown below.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


client = MongoClient() 
db = client.admin # run commands against admin database.

db.command('enableSharding',  'mongotest')
db.command({'shardCollection': 'mongotest.signals', 'key': {'valueX': 1, 'valueY': 1}})
```

However, you may want to confirm that both enableSharding and shardCollection are exposed in your db by running

```
db.command('listCommands')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You have been a great help to me.
Just one more thing.  It is not necessary that the sharded keys (valueX and valueY) are previously indexed? 
regards.